# Regular expression to find Table Aliases and fields in a sql query using Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string which contains a very long and complex query.

What I want is that one of my tables has a alias `T_1`; I would like to get all the literals in the query which are referred through `T_1`.

For example, if the query is

```
Select T_1.Name, 
       T_1.Age 
  from Demo T_1,
       Table2 T_2 
 where T_1.EmpId = T_2.EmpId;
```

then I should match the following strings:

1. `Name`
2. `Age`
3. `EmpId`

Comment: Works like a charm ,thanks @AvinashRaj !

Answer (score 1):

The question was already answered by [Avinash Raj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297613/)  in the comments, but here the complete answer:

Assuming you are using java the code you need is something like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\.)\\w+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Select T_1.Name, \n" +
        "       T_1.Age \n" +
        "  from Demo T_1,\n" +
        "       Table2 T_2 \n" +
        " where T_1.EmpId = T_2.EmpId;");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```